# Square Payment Gatway throwing error Error: Tokenization has failed, the tokenization request is already in process

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, square

I am using Square .net Web Payments for checkout on my website. I am using the following library from Square: https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/csharp_payment  . It works fine on .net c#... payment is processing and is successful but my project is Asp.net Core MVC so when i import the above c# project to mvc and add all Razor pages settings in Program.cs and add all AppSettings like ApplicationId, AccessToken and Location Is, it does not process payment, the card page loads fine but payment is not processing, it is throwing following error after i input sandbox credit card details:

Error: Tokenization has failed
the tokenization request is already in process

So it is not processing the payment.  I think it maybe because i switch to MVC and i need to do something for the library to be useful.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved, i had to add a / when routing to process-payment page, it now processes the payment fine.